# Win32 message timeout clears my window

Tags: winapi, win32gui

Take the simplest possible Windows program with a window and message loop, such as a Hello, World program.

Suppose that just before I enter the message loop, I draw into the window (naughtily done outside processing of wm_paint, but bear with me).

If I spend more than about 5 seconds doing this, or I draw something then spend 5 seconds doing something else, before I start the message loop, then the message system seems to 'time out'. The MSDN docs for PeekMessage says it becomes 'unresponsive' and turns it into a 'ghost' window.

My problem however is that it also clears the contents of the window!

Is there way of stopping it doing that? The same 'unresponsive' caption is shown if I spend too long drawing into the window even during offical wm_paint processing; it also starts to behave oddly by generating more wm_paint messages.

It seems very restrictive if everything (eg. complicated rendering, or image processing) must be done within 5 seconds, or if any algorithm needs to keep prodding the message queue to stop it timing out!

Comment: If you want a responsive UI you need to respond to messages in a timely manner. I don't see much of a restriction outside of logical necessities. Your observations with respect to `WM_PAINT` messages is also incorrect: There will not ever be more than one `WM_PAINT` message in the message queue. In fact, there isn't even a single `WM_PAINT` message in the queue; it is generated by a message retrieval function, if the invalid area is non-empty, and there aren't any higher priority messages in the message queue.

Comment: The ghosting feature is described on MSDN: [Preventing Hangs in Windows Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd744765.aspx).  It can be disabled with [`DisableProcessWindowsGhosting()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648415.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is by design.  You must keep checking for messages so that you can respond to user events such as resizing or closing the window.  Even worse, if your application is not responding to events then that may cause other applications to freeze, as they may send your application a message and be stuck waiting for a reply.

If you have to do a lot of processing then either check for messages periodically, or do the work in a separate thread.

Comment: OK, but the context is as follows: I'm creating a simple graphics library to be used by a simple interpreted language that does not want to know about message time-outs or re-painting. It puts something on the screen and expects it to stay there!

Getting around this time-out is going to be awkward and/or slow things down. And I can't stop user-code invoking an external process which can take more than 5 seconds to complete, by which time the message  system is in a panic. Perhaps I need to start looking at threads but I've never used them before.

Comment: You can't really expect things to stay on the screen anyway, it'll get erased in various situations beyond your control.  What you should do is: 1) Have your language in its own thread, and have it paint to a memory device context (DC).  2) In your main thread, on WM_PAINT, you just copy from the memory DC to the screen.  You'll need to use a critical section to make sure both threads don't write to the DC at once.

Comment: I can deal with this by getting my interpreter to call PeekMessage once every second or so (a nuisance because it has to be dealt with at bytecode level; it can affect performance). But it won't work when the program calls another long process (eg. system()) which it waits for. Is there a way of suspending the message system for a period?

Comment: @bartc: If your interpreter/language runtime runs on the GUI thread, you should revisit your design. Offload the computation to a worker thread, and have it notify the GUI thread, where necessary. This is how virtually **all** applications with a graphical user interface are implemented, irrespective of the platform.

Answer (score 0):

create a thread for extensive drawing on a cache bitmap. while bitmap is not ready just print on WM_PAIN event "processing please wait..." for example. when ready print that bitmap. and destroy the thread.